# Text input value does not display on page load until select option is changed

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, sidebar

I am trying to load options into a select box from a Google Sheet. My code currently almost works, however, the initial select option is not loading the corresponding value into the text input box when the page first displays. When the select box option is changed, the value is properly loaded into the text box. How can I load both the option and value on the initial page load?

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Sidebar")
    .addItem("Show sidebar", "showSidebar")
    .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var htmlWidget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Test')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlWidget);
}

function getList() { 
  var items = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!A1:B3").getValues();
  return items;
}
```

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <script>
    function loadSelectBox() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
      {
        var itemList = document.getElementById("itemSelectBox");
        ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
        {    
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = item[1];
          option.text = item[0];
          itemList.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getList(); 
      getPath();
   }

    function getPath() 
    {
      var path = document.getElementById("itemSelectBox").value;
      document.getElementById("itemPath").value = path;
    }
  </script>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <select id="itemSelectBox" onchange="getPath()" style="width: 60%"></select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="itemPath" style="width: 60%">
    <script>
      loadSelectBox();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `loadSelectBox()` as follows.

```
function loadSelectBox() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (ar) {
    var itemList = document.getElementById("itemSelectBox");
    ar.forEach(function (item, index) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item[1];
      option.text = item[0];
      itemList.appendChild(option);
    });
    getPath(); // <--- Modified
  }).getList();
}
```

- In your showing script, `getPath();` is put outside of `google.script.run`. `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. By this, before `withSuccessHandler` is run, `getPath()` is run. I thought that this is the reason for your issue.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, the code is working correctly. I also tried loading the array into a scriptlet and changing HTML output to template with evaluate. However, the scriptlet <? ... ?> wasn't recognized in the JS code sections but I can see in the console it properly pulled in the array data.

Comment: @MeesterZee Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the scriptlet, I thought that [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) might be useful for understanding the HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have the javascript in the header and thus it's run before the dom (html) is created.

You can
a) move your javascript into a  in the end
b) trigger your code once https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event is fired.

alternative a might work better but it's not pretty to have html and JS mixed unless you really have to.